# Fastest way of deseriallizing JSON C#

Tags: c#, javascript, json, performance, json.net

I have list of JSON strings which may contain 1000-2000 records per string. The list count may be around 100,000. I tried to use JSON.net (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject), System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode and JavascriptSerializer.Deserialize (i followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object) post and used DynamicJsonConverter). In a performance comparison, JavascriptSerializer.Deserialize works quite better than others but still it does not meet my requirements. I need to know that what could be the most efficient way of de-serializing JSON into object/dynamic. Or if someone would like to share performance benchmark of de-serializing JSON would be very helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

JSON.NET is always performant.

Old, but relevant:
http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2010/01/01/net-serialization-performance-comparison

Comment: Very good link thanks. I didn't know there was a lib specially built for JSON in .NET. I used to be pretty happy with the `JavascriptSerializer`.

Comment: I am using following code to de-serialize, please guide me if it could be optimize.     JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyObj>>(json);